# Disable image button border

Tags: css, asp.net, imagebutton

I'm using asp.net ImageButton and it looks like:

[image]

I want to remove that blue border.
I have tried

```
border: 0px;
border-style:none;
```

But same result.. How can I solve that?

I'm using that for voting system and I want to execute some server side code on this button click

Comment: `<asp:ImageButton ID="btn" runat="server" border="0"></asp:ImageButton>`

Comment: as Leo said, make ensure that the border is not part of the image.

Comment: How are you setting the image? Via URL ou CSS background image?

Comment: @chiapa via css background image

Comment: Could you try setting it via URL if that doesn't disarrange you? It may fix the problem

Comment: yeah I have dont that and it works. thanks a lot @chiapa

Comment: Glad I could help, just posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting your image as a CSS background, this issue may solvable by setting the image via URL.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the border is NOT part of the image. This is what you can try:

1. `border:none;`
2. `outline:none`
3. append the `!important` declaration just in case there is some overriding your styles

#### Example

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnLike" runat="server" style="border:none !important;outline:none !important" .../>
```

#### Update based on comment

Since you are setting the image as a background image (dunnot why since you're already using an `ImageButton`) make sure that the background of your button has no color...`background-color: transparent`

Comment: no that border is not a part of image. and that code too doesn't works.. :\

Comment: @George then I can blindly say that your problem is something else. If you are unable to debug it on your own then you will need to at least reproduce this issue in JS Fiddler or something similar

Comment: It solved as chipa said.. thanks for reply. thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

Create class like this and choose your image to show on button. include class in button. see below :

**Css Style :**

```
.btn {border:none; background:url(image/loader.gif); }
```

**Your Button Code :**

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this , in CSS file

```
 border: 0px solid transparent;
 outline: transparent solid 0px;
```